# delay in database result

Tags: php, mysql

Ive done a search page where you can add each item as a favorite. What I can see is that the code does correct in everything except the result. When you press a favorite it is stored correctly in the database, but does not appear immediately after adiing it. It works after approx 20sec, then press refresh in the browser and then it is displayed correctly.

Please give tips what I can do to understand the problem, thanks.

Here is a link to test:

http://www.boxstar.se/test/search.php

And here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

//open connection to db
include("connectdb.inc.php");

//read session variables
$current_user_id = 1;

//get value from url passed from other page
$var_value = $_GET['area'];

//Get the posts from table data
$search_query_data="SELECT * FROM magasinera";
$search_result_data = mysqli_query($conn, $search_query_data) or die('Error, query failed, query 1');



//if favorite button pressed, then enter here
if (isset($_POST['favorite_x'])) { 

    //get values from form
    $adid = $_POST['adid'];

    //Get the posts from favorites
    $favorite_query="SELECT * FROM favoriter WHERE userid = '$current_user_id' AND adid = '$adid'" ;
    $favorite_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $favorite_query) or die('Error, query failed, query 2');

    $num_rows = $favorite_posts->num_rows;

    if ($num_rows==0) {
      $insert_favorite="INSERT INTO favoriter (userid, adid) VALUES ('$current_user_id','$adid')";
      $stmt_insert_favorite = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_favorite) or die('Error, query failed, query 3');
    }
header("Refresh:0");
exit;
} //End isset Post


//if favorite button pressed, then enter here
if (isset($_POST['rensa'])) { 

    //Delete from favoriter
    $Clear_query="DELETE FROM favoriter";
    $favorite_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $Clear_query) or die('Error, query failed, query 2');
header("Refresh:0");
exit;
} //End isset Post
?>

<html>
<body>
   <!--  START code for database presentation -->
   <form name="search_area" method="get" action="search.php">
      <!-- Search function -->
      <table border="0" style="width: 200px;">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <select id="area" name="area" style="height: 50px; width: 200px; font-size:24px;">
                  <option value="New York" <?php if($var_value=="New York") { echo "selected";} ?>>New York</option>
                  <option value="Los Angeles" <?php if($var_value=="Los Angeles") { echo "selected";} ?>>Los Angeles</option>
                  <option value="Chicago" <?php if($var_value=="Chicago") { echo "selected";} ?>>Chicago</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><button type="submit" class="button" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"><span>Search</span></button></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
   <br>

   <hr>
   <?php
    // LOOP SHOW SEARCH RESULT, query from row 46
    while ($row_search_result2 = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result_data)) {

        $adid = $row_search_result2['Adid'];
        $str_omr2 = $row_search_result2['Omrade'];

        //Get the posts from favorites
        $favorite_query2 = "SELECT * FROM favoriter WHERE userid = '$current_user_id' AND adid = '$adid'" ;
        $favorite_posts2 = mysqli_query($conn, $favorite_query2) or die('Error, query failed');
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($favorite_posts2);

        if ($str_omr2 == $var_value) {    

        ?>

        <?php echo "Number of rows in db :  " . $num_rows; ?> 

            <!-- <hr> -->
            <form name="login" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">

                  <?php
                  //Check if favorite is present in db, if not
                  if ($num_rows==0) {
                  ?>
                     <input type="image" src="favorit.png" title="Add as favorite" name="favorite">

                  <?php

                  //If favorite exist in db   
                  } else {
                  ?>   
                     <img src="favorit2.png" title="The ad is added as favorite">
                  <?php                  
                  }
               ?>   
                <input type="hidden" name="adid" value="<?php echo $row_search_result2['Adid']; ?>">
            </form>  
        <?php
        echo "Adid: " . $adid;
        echo ",  ";     
        echo "Userid: " . $current_user_id;
        ?>
        <br><br><br>
        <?php
        }  // End if
        ?> <br><br><br>  <?php
    }  //END WHILE($row_search_result = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)
    ?>
    <br><br><br>

    <form name="rensa" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
      <button type="submit" class="button" name="rensa" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">Rensa</button>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `ob_start();`? You use `if (isset($_POST['favorite_x'])` but I can not find any `favorite_x` field anywhere in your code, only `favorite`.